# Passing along invites to beta web apps like thieves in the night

Tags: discussion, users

Where should we be handing out invites for beta phase web apps?

Is chat more appropriate than the meta here? Or how should we connect with other Web Apps users to pass these along so as to not clutter up the wrong, or least desired, spot?

Some of us might come across web apps that aren't yet in the wild and pantsless free world and it wouldn't hurt to have more people using said web services and apps to help answer questions we may have.

The sticking point is that many of these invites are passed along via email, so dropping a link to sign up might not work out most of the time.

Comment: Shouldn't it be part of this program?

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102582/were-ready-to-beta-test-our-beta-tester-matchmaking-program

Comment: Looks like Web Apps got left off of that list @ale

Comment: There's a comment from Abby Miller about web apps: "Just sign up on the developer spreadsheet and mention that it's a webapp in the 'other info' box."

Comment: They have no mention for the end user though. Which would be nice to see if our band of users here could get in on some of that ground floor action @ale

Comment: I've suggested it.

Answer (score 2):

Chat would seem the best place to do this - but for it's lack of activity.

To drum up support we could allow questions (or better still an answer to a "sign up for betas" question here on meta.

This should take a predefined format - much the same way as the community ads answers - and include a link to chat where the actual swapping of e-mail addresses takes place.

Comment: Should this be one chat for all betas? One for each service? Or disposable "dropbox" chat rooms that are destroyed for each swap?

Comment: @phwd - I don't know. I hadn't thought that far ahead ;)

Comment: One chat for all betas sounds cleaner, at least it would be an easy way to spot where the dumping is happening. Not like we couldn't make use of the current Web Apps room and move it out if there's too much noise @phw

Comment: Alright well sounds good to me the only thing will be the passing of the emails in the open. Whoever wants to be granted beta invites will just have to be open to that.

Comment: @phwd There's no way round that unless people start following each other on Twitter, or connect on LinkedIn etc. and use their private message facilities.

Comment: There's also stuff like http://scr.im if people wanted to pass it about and not have it directly in the face there. @phw

Comment: Let's get'er done then @EightDaysofMalaise

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we could use this meta and create a community wiki post. This allows users at 100 rep and above to edit, since you can't suggest edits on child metas.

The only answer on that would then have subheadings on the service and below that, a list of users and or means to get invites.

Something like this:

> #### Blubrry App
>
> service to keep track of your blueberries
>
> - scr.im/blahbla - from name of Web Apps user
> - pingu@example.com - from name of another Web Apps user
>
> #### Bananaramalamadingdongadong
>
> share and geolocate the best places to eat bananas
>
> - bana.nr/invites/crazyCODE - from name of Web Apps user

And when those invites are gone, the user handing them out will come back and remove their feed line from that section of the post.

#### Coded links

Some of these services will require you to send out an invite email which will include a special link. Users who don't want to bother changing out emails could instead send an email to themselves or a junk email they'd watch and collect these generated coded links to paste under each web app heading.